# having validator on inputtext results in nullpointerexception

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a popup with a few inputtext fields & a button which calls a method to create.

On one of the field, when I add a validator="#{uBean.validateName}", the validator works fine & validates the field & raises exception if the validation fails. But clicking on the create button is raising nullpointerexception.

Any ideas why?

I found this with the same issue:
http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2009/04/unexpected-null-pointer-exception-in-oracle-adf.html#sthash.3EyJZ4zK.dpbs

But it talks about removing the validator to fix the issue but I do need the validator.

Comment: please post your popup code and backing bean code.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using  JSF validators.
I would rather recommend you to replace your JSF Validator with a Business Components Level validation, like [Method Validator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16182/bcrules.htm#ADFFD455) on attribute.

Aditionally you will need to set autosubmit="true" on that particular input JSF component.

Comment: The fields are written to a backingBean & the button calls a custom java class. I don't have a business component or an entity model.